# Using make for cross platform compilation

Tags: c, makefile, cross-platform

I am currently developing a C project under Linux and Win32. The 'deliverable' is a shared library, and all the development is done under Linux with the GNU tool chain. I am using a Makefile to compile the shared library.

Every now and then I have to build a .dll under Win32 from the same src.

I've installed MinGW on the Win32 box such that I can use make and get *far* fewer complaints from the compiler (in comparison to MSVC). I'm at a stage where the src code compiles on both platforms

But the Linux Makefile and Win32 Makefile are different. I'm curious as how to best handle this - should I:

1. have 2 makefiles, e.g. Makefile for linux and Makefile.WIN32 and then run `make -f Makefile.WIN32` on the Windows box
2. Should I make a different target in a single Makefile and do something like `make WIN32` on the Windows box
3. Should I ditch make and use CMake (is the juice worth the squeeze for such a simple project, i.e. 1 shared library)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use a single make file and put the platform-specifics in [conditionals](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Conditionals), eg

```
ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT)
    DLLEXT := .dll
else
    DLLEXT := .so
endif

DLL := libfoo$(DLLEXT)

lib : $(DLL)
```

Comment: While this approach arguably has some issues (not very modular, re-running feature-detection on every `make` invocation), I don't think they matter for your use case; also, GNU make *is* powerful enough to build a configuration system on top of it (eg you can auto-generate makefile snippets to `include` and run arbitrary code via `$(shell)`, produce diagnostics via `$(info)` and `$(error)`, ...)

Comment: http://oreilly.com/catalog/make3/book/ch07.pdf Check this book for writing portable Makefile.

Answer (score 21):

I use `UNAME := $(shell uname)` within my `Makefile` to detect the platform (Linux or MS-Windows).

I provide below a complete example based on `make` and `gcc` to build a shared library: `*.so` or `*.dll` depending on the platform.

The example is basic/simple/stupid to be more understandable :-)

To use `make` and `gcc` on MS-Windows, [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/install.html) or [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Getting_Started) can be installed.

The example uses five files:

```
 ├── app
 │   └── Makefile
 │   └── main.c
 └── lib
     └── Makefile
     └── hello.h
     └── hello.c
```

### The `Makefiles`

**`app/Makefile`**

```
app.exe: main.o
        gcc -o $@ $^ -L../lib -lhello
        # '-o $@'    => output file => $@ = the target file (app.exe)
        # '   $^'    => no options => Link all depended files 
        #            => $^ = main.o and other if any
        # '-L../lib' => look for libraries in directory ../lib
        # '-lhello   => use shared library hello (libhello.so or hello.dll)

%.o: %.c
        gcc -o $@ -c $< -I ../lib
        # '-o $@'     => output file => $@ = the target file (main.o)
        # '-c $<'     => COMPILE the first depended file (main.cpp)
        # '-I ../lib' => look for headers (*.h) in directory ../lib

clean:
        rm -f *.o *.so *.dll *.exe
```

**`lib/Makefile`**

```
UNAME := $(shell uname)

ifeq ($(UNAME), Linux)
TARGET = libhello.so
else
TARGET = hello.dll
endif

$(TARGET): hello.o
        gcc  -o $@  $^  -shared
        # '-o $@'    => output file => $@ = libhello.so or hello.dll
        # '   $^'    => no options => Link all depended files => $^ = hello.o
        # '-shared'  => generate shared library

%.o: %.c
        gcc  -o $@  -c $<  -fPIC
        # '-o $@' => output file => $@ = the target file (main.o)
        # '-c $<' => compile the first depended file (main.cpp)
        # '-fPIC' => Position-Independent Code (required for shared lib)

clean:
        rm -f *.o *.so *.dll *.exe
```

### The source code

**`app/main.c`**

```
#include "hello.h" //hello()
#include <stdio.h> //puts()

int main()
{
    const char* str = hello();
    puts(str);
}
```

**`lib/hello.h`**

```
#ifndef __HELLO_H__
#define __HELLO_H__

const char* hello();

#endif
```

**`lib/hello.c`**

```
#include "hello.h"

const char* hello()
{
    return "hello";
}
```

### The build

Fix the copy-paste of `Makefiles` (replace leading spaces by tabulation).

```
> sed  -i  's/^  */\t/'  */Makefile
```

The `make` command is the same on both platforms. The given output is for MS-Windows (unnecessary lines removed).

```
> cd lib
> make clean
> make
gcc  -o hello.o  -c hello.c  -fPIC
gcc  -o hello.dll  hello.o  -shared
> cd ../app
> make clean
> make
gcc -o main.o -c main.c -I ../lib
gcc -o app.exe main.o -L../lib -lhello
```

### The run

The application requires to know where is the shared library.

On MS-Windows, the simple/basic/stupid way is to copy the library where the application is:

```
> cp -v lib/hello.dll app
`lib/hello.dll' -> `app/hello.dll'
```

On Linux, use the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable:

```
> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=lib
```

The run command line and output are the same on both platforms:

```
> app/app.exe
hello
```

Answer (score 7):

As somebody who has used both autotools and CMake, I would recommend using CMake over rolling your own Makefiles and using autotools.  CMake has so many useful, easy to use benefits, even if it is a simple project.  For example, CMake will create an NSIS installer, manage production vs. debug compilation and has a nice testing framework.  The one knock I had was that it was kind of hard to find real examples of how to use it.  So much open source software uses autotools that realworld examples for it are easy to find.  However, if you download the CMake source, there are lots of examples in the Example directory and Test directory.

In other words, the Juice is worth the squeeze.

Comment: links to said sources?

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue a few years back, and found that  [cmake](http://www.cmake.org/) is much easier for cross-platform compilation AND will use whatever compiler is native for that system.  Syntax is clearer and abstracts details that are unnecessary for the most part (sometimes that got in the way, but usually there was a way around it)

Comment: Do you need to write a toolchain file to get CMake to pick up gcc, or does it auto-detect MinGW and choose that over MSVC?

Comment: You just specify which compiler you want by specifying a generator (option -G).  Details are at http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#section_Generators.

Comment: I always used VS2010 on windows and GCC on *nix, both of which were automatically picked up.  If you don't have VS, it might auto-detect and use MinGW, but you can always specify the generator if it doesn't auto-detect

Comment: I would not say that CMake is useful for cross-platform compilation. It is useful for _multi-platform_, in that one set of CMake files can be used on all platforms that CMake supports. It does not easily lend itself to creating some sort of make files on one platform that can then be used without CMake on other platforms though. It also doesn't understand cross-compilers that compile for one platform on a different one.

Answer (score 3):

As a primary advice, I suggest using libtool, autoconf and automake; they make cross-compilation very easy, and much easier than CMake.

If you are going the hand-crafted route, I would suggest going with different targets. Switching between makefiles tends to hide otherwise obvious errors in Makefiles, e.g. duplicately used objects with different rules. Example: The object foo.o is compiled for the DLL target and for the .so target, but with different flags. If someone switches Makefiles, the existing .o file with wrong flags is used, breaking the build. If you are using one Makefile, this will become obvious through rule conflicts.

Comment: autotools are great when they work, but that's not always the case; for example, I only got git to build on MinGW via providing explicit configuration arguments to `make`, and not via the automated system...

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to use MSYS2 on Windows you might get it to run *without
making any changes at all* compared to your code written for Linux.
This goes for your C/C++ source code as well as for your makefile.(!)

I have been developing code for Linux exclusively. When I tried running it
inside an MSYS2 terminal, the code turned out to work just fine, and
produced a Windows binary executable. I was positively surprised.

You will need to know how to install and use MSYS2, of course. For example,
to install make and g++, in an MSYS2 terminal run the commands:

```
yes | pacman -Syu msys/make
yes | pacman -Syu gcc
```

If you want to find out where in Windows g++ has been installed, you can run
`where g++` in the MSYS2 terminal.

References:
https://www.msys2.org/wiki/MSYS2-installation/
https://github.com/msys2/MSYS2-packages/issues/293
[image: https://superuser.com/questions/21067/windows-equivalent-of-whereis#39309]