# Unable to run Jenkins C++ artifact

Tags: c++, eclipse, jenkins, makefile

I have a simple "hello world" C++ project: https://github.com/RomainGoussault/Deepov

I use Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers (on Windows8) which is generating the makefile.
I can run the .exe file produced by Eclipse but I cannot run the .exe file produced by Jenkins (my Jenkins instance is on a linux server, hosted by cloudbees). I have the following  Windows 8 error message.

> "This app can't run on your PC"

If I run the .exe file as administrator I have got another error message:

> Windows cannot find 'C:\User\Romain\Downloads\Deepov.exe'. Make sure
>   you've typed the name correctly, then try again.

The Jenkins build is simply executing the following shell commands:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "*********building************"
echo $WORKSPACE
cd $WORKSPACE/Debug
echo $PWD
make clean
make
```

Note: The makefile can be found here: https://github.com/RomainGoussault/Deepov/blob/master/Debug/makefile

Comment: Are you using Eclipse also on Linux?

Comment: For now I use Eclipse on Win8

Comment: Hmmm...can you try running the Jenkins built .exe as Administrator?

Comment: Can you try placing the exe in `C:\\` and then try running?

Comment: I have a similar error message: Windows cannot find 'C:\Deepov.exe'. Make sure you've typed the name correctly, then try again.

Comment: Then it might be related to compatibility of the exe built on Linux. You can try setting up a Jenkins standalone on your Win box to confirm though that might be too much of an effort. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pretty sure `make` is platform dependent. Here is a question discussing cross-platform make:

[Using make for cross platform compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9791127/using-make-for-cross-platform-compilation)